# Dissolve Boundaries results in increased Shape_area than sum of parts using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: dissolve

I have a series of overlapping/intersecting features from 3 years of data.

I buffered all feature types so they were polygons and then merged them. I made sure to map the fields. The buffers used were the actual values from the data and very nearly match those used in the excel calculations, though the stored value for the buffers was the max in ArcGIS Pro but we wanted to actually use the median in analysis. I am not the owner and cannot change the stored value.

Most features were very small and I don't *think* this explains the drastic increase.  It is usually a couple of meters max difference. When I dissolve the boundaries of this merged feature on species name, the shape area is far larger than the sum of the parts. Intuitively this number should be lower. For example: 3 polygons sit roughly on top of one another. The sum of the area for those 3 polygons is 100m.

So if I dissolve those 3 polygons into one polygon, shouldn't the area be about 1/3 of the previous sum?

In the original data (analyzed in excel and including sum of overlapping area) the total for this species is 10.4 acres. The sum for the buffered merged features is 42.6 acres, and the dissolved acres is 21.9 acres. See attached screenshots of 1) the merged data for a single species (yellow) and 2) the dissolved feature for that same species (red).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you test your workflow on some well known test data like 2-3 intersecting squares or circles?

Comment: I am working in ArcPro. This example actually is a small test site of just one species. I guess I could do it on a single record of each feature type and see if I gain any insights.